# How can trigonometric ratios of 90° be found?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The angles in a right triangle can never be 90° (excluding the right angle ofcourse). Then how can T-ratios of 90°  be found? Leaving "finding them"  aside, how can they even exist? Same goes for T-rations of angles bigger than 90° .

I am a 10th class student and have studied trig for thr first time so sorry if this is a dumb question..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions

Comment: Good question.Great question. The answer is that the sine function is "extended" to these regions, using either limit processes or other definitions, such as the one given by coordinate geometry, or Menelaus' theorem.

Comment: Thy to conceive of an abstract triangle with $opp = 1$, $adj = 0$, and $hyp = 1$.

Comment: how can a triangle have a side = 0 units??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigonometric functions are not defined using a right triangle for angles greater than 90°. Rather, they are defined like this:

[image: Sine and cosine from the unit circle]

Here we have the origin O and a point P that is a unit distance away from O, and the (anticlockwise) angle OP makes with the *x*-axis is $\theta$. Then $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ are the *y*- and *x*-coordinates of P respectively.

This definition using the unit circle extends the sine and cosine functions to all angles, and shows that the functions are periodic with period $2\pi/360^\circ$.

Once we have the sine and cosine defined, the tangent is defined by the identity
$$\tan\theta\equiv\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$$
and the cosecant/secant/cotangent functions are the reciprocals of the sine/cosine/tangent functions respectively.

As an example, we have $\sin90^\circ=1$ but $\cos90^\circ=0$, so $\tan90^\circ$ is undefined ("infinity").

Comment: "Here we have the origin O and a point P that is a unit distance away from O, and the (anticlockwise) angle OP makes with the x-axis is θθ." I can't locate the angels..help plz

Comment: What? I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: where are the points O and P?

Comment: In the animated image, O is the centre of the yellow circle. P is the point that's going around it.

Comment: "This definition using the unit circle extends the sine and cosine functions to all angles, and shows that the functions are periodic with period 2π/360∘2π/360∘." Cant understand this line either...what does period mean?

Comment: If I add $2\pi$ radians or $360^\circ$ to the argument of any of the trigonometric functions, I get the same result. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function), for more on periods.

Comment: oh, this is soo cool. Can you gimme the derivation or the way that mathematicians came up with this method, or is it too high level for me?

Comment: The derivation is trivial. There are only 360 degrees in a circle, so adding or subtracting 360 degrees to $\theta$ just brings $P$ back to where it started!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45010/discussion-between-adi-and-parcly-taxel).

Comment: Clichéd response. I'm on my phone, I can't chat! And I should have explained most of the stuff you need to know to understand this.

Comment: oh, k thx!! This is rly cool